# ALU + Shift Reg

Tags: vhdl

I have to make a 8-bit ALU which is connected  to a shift register. I think this is the code for a ALU but what is the best way to connect it too 8-bit shift register with a reset and clock? Im not sure how to use an internal signal to connect these two components, should they both have separate

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;              -- Calling libary's to be used
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity lu is
port(   Clk : in std_logic;                -- The clock signal
        A : in signed(7 downto 0);         -- The A Input
        B : in signed(7 downto 0);         -- The B Input
        OPCODE : in unsigned(2 downto 0);  -- Op code entered into ALU
        RES :in  std_logic;                -- The reset pin
        Q : out signed(7 downto 0)         -- The Output of LU
        );
end lu;                                    -- End Entity


architecture Behavioral of lu is

signal Reg1,Reg2,Reg3 : signed(7 downto 0) := (others => '0'); --The signal declaration 

begin

Reg1 <= A;        -- Linking Reg1 Signal to Input A
Reg2 <= B;        -- Linking Reg2 Signal to Input B
Q <= Reg3;        -- Linking Output Q to Signal Reg3

process(Clk)

begin

    if(rising_edge(Clk)) then -- Calculate at the positive edge of clk
        case OPCODE is

            when "000" => 
                Reg3 <= Reg1 + Reg2;    -- Output is = to addition

            when "001" => 
                Reg3 <= Reg1 - Reg2;    -- Output is = to subtraction

            when "010" => 
                Reg3 <= not Reg1;       -- Output is = to NOT gate

            when "011" => 
                Reg3 <= Reg1 nand Reg2; -- Output is = to NAND gate 

            when "100" => 
                Reg3 <= Reg1 nor Reg2;  -- Output is = to NOR gate  

            when "101" => 
                Reg3 <= Reg1 and Reg2;  -- Output is = to AND gate

            when "110" => 
                Reg3 <= Reg1 or Reg2;   -- Output is = to OR gate 

            when "111" => 
                Reg3 <= Reg1 xor Reg2;  -- Output is = to XOR gate  


            when others =>              -- If anyother Input Outputs nothing
                NULL;

        end case;       
    end if;

end process;    

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want the ALU to use the shift register, and to achieve what? You can connect it up in all sorts of different ways, but you need to define the function more precisely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean to add logical operations to the ALU code provided, you need to make two changes:

1) In the ports list, increase the width of your `opcode` signal so that you can add new opcode values:

```
    OPCODE: in unsigned(3 downto 0); -- Operation selection for the ALU
```

2) In your case statement, simply add the new conditions and the code to perform the logical operations:

```
    case OPCODE is
        ...

        when "1000" =>
            Reg3 <= Reg1 srl to_integer(Reg2);  -- Reg3 <= Reg1 shifted Reg2 bits to the right
        when "1001" =>
            Reg3 <= Reg1 sll to_integer(Reg2);  -- Reg3 <= Reg1 shifted Reg2 bits to the left
        when "1010" =>
            Reg3 <= Reg1 ror to_integer(Reg2);  -- Reg3 <= Reg1 rotated Reg2 bits to the right
        when "1011" =>
            Reg3 <= Reg1 rol to_integer(Reg2);  -- Reg3 <= Reg1 rotated Reg2 bits to the right
        when others =>
            Reg3 <= (others => '0');
    end case;
```